# teradata yymmdd date format

Tags: date, format, teradata

I have a field that should be 6 digit character but it is numeric.  I am using the following code to add the leading zero:

select CAST(CAST(CHD_OPEN_DATE AS FORMAT '9(6)') AS CHAR(9))

I'm using the following code to format this as a date:

cast(cast(lpad(to_char(CHD_OPEN_DATE),6,'0') as date format 'YYMMDD') as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')

When using this date format 1990 comes up as 2090.  Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: You mean *900331* is '1990-03-31'  while *170331* translates to '2017-03-31'? What's the cut-off year?

Comment: I'm not sure what the cut off year is.  If you can show me how to set it up using 1910?  I will make that work for now and investigate further on what the proper date is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your number has a `YYMMDD` format you can use the following to cast to a date without the need to cast to an intermediate string. Assuming a date range between 1930 and 2029:

```
SELECT 900331 AS CHD_OPEN_DATE,
Cast(CASE WHEN CHD_OPEN_DATE < 300000
          THEN CHD_OPEN_DATE + 1000000
          ELSE CHD_OPEN_DATE
     END AS DATE)
```